# Decorating a decorator using a function - why does the following not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I am struggling to understand the following behaviour of decorated decorators - could someone help me please?

Basically, I have a `decorator_for_decorator` function that decorates a decorator:

```
def decorator_for_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Decorator successfully decorated')
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper
```

When I decorate my decorator like this:

```
# this doesn't work
@decorator_for_decorator
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Function successfully decorated')
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

def apply_decorator(func):
    func = decorator(func)
    return func

def f1():
    print('hello')

f2 = apply_decorator(f1)

f2()
```

The call to f2() returns:

```
Function successfully decorated
hello
```

Indicating that the decorator_for_decorator did not decorate my decorator. However, if I instead decorate my decorator like this:

```
# this works
def decorator(func):
    @decorator_for_decorator
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Function successfully decorated')
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

f2 = apply_decorator(f1)

f2()
```

Calling f2() returns:

```
Decorator successfully decorated
Function successfully decorated
hello
```

Why is this the case? I would expect both ways to decorate the decorator to work but it seems like only the latter works.

Comment: If I combine your first two code blocks and run them, I get "Decorator successfully decorated" and the rest of the output.

Comment: In the first case, this code `f2 = apply_decorator(f1)` should print `Decorator successfully decorated` which is when `decorator` is called. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: "Indicating that the decorator_for_decorator did not decorate my decorator." It does not indicate this. If you try running the code all in order, you will see the `Decorator successfully decorated` output. It just doesn't come from calling f2, because, **why should it**? That's *not the code that causes the decorator to be decorated*!

Comment: So yes, in the first case, applying the decorator (not calling the function) does print `decorator successfully decorated`, but subsequently calling f2() does not print this.

If I apply the second code snippet, *calling* f2() does print `decorator successfully decorated` 

I'm confused because in the former case, some code I expect to run when I call f2() is not running.

Shouldn't both decorators decorate my function in the same way? Why should it matter where I'm placing the @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think the confusion comes from when a decorator runs.

Let's break down this example, the one you marked as *this doesn't work*

```py
def decorator_for_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Decorator successfully decorated')
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

@decorator_for_decorator
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Function successfully decorated')
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

def apply_decorator(func):
    func = decorator(func)
    return func

def f1():
    print('hello')
```

When you call:

```py
f2 = apply_decorator(f1)
```

The execution path is:

1. the function `apply_decorator` is called, with argument `f1`
2. we are now inside `apply_decorator`, which calls the `decorator` function, passing the argument received (so `f1`)
3. the function `decorator` is decorated with `decorator_for_decorator`, which means we now have to execute `decorator_for_decorator`.
4. we are now inside `decorator_for_decorator` and we are executing it (since it has been called from being a decorator). The output `"Decorator successfully decorated"` is printed on screen.
5. we continue execution going back inside `decorator`, which returns a function. Only when this returned function is called it will execute, printing the line `Function successfully decorated`, but note as we are never executing the function here, since we never call the returned function `f2` from `f2 = apply_decorator(f1)`

The code execution now stops. We have a function `f2` ready to be used.

What happens when we call `f2()`? Let's see

1. calling `f2` basically runs the code returned by `func = decorator(func)`
2. we run the function returned by `decorator`, which prints `"Function successfully decorated"` and then executes whichever function has been passed in, in our case it's `f1`
3. we execute `f1`, printing `"hello"` and we finish.

Now, if you call `f2()` again, you will re-do the exact same execution as above, so it will print `"Function successfully decorated"` and then `"hello"`.

You get `"Decorator successfully decorated"` only once, after calling `f2 = apply_decorator(f1)`, because this is when the decorator applied to `def decorator(func):` is supposed to run.

Now, let's look at the other example:

```py
def decorator_for_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Decorator successfully decorated')
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

def decorator(func):
    @decorator_for_decorator
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Function successfully decorated')
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

def apply_decorator(func):
    func = decorator(func)
    return func

def f1():
    print('hello')

f2 = apply_decorator(f1)
```

The execution path is:

1. the function `apply_decorator` is called, with argument `f1`
2. we are now inside `apply_decorator`, which calls the `decorator` function, passing the argument received (so `f1`)
3. the function `decorator` is NOT decorated with `decorator_for_decorator`, but it's the function `wrapper` inside that it is decorated and the decorator runs only when the decorated function runs. In this case, it will run only when `wrapper` runs.
4. we return without printing anything on screen.

What happens now when we call `f2()`?

1. as before, calling `f2` calls the function returned by `func = decorator(func)`
2. we run the function returned by `decorator`, which is `wrapper`. Now, this function is decorated by `@decorator_for_decorator`, so we have to run `decorator_for_decorator first.
3. We print on screen `"Decorator successfully decorated"`
4. We now run `wrapper` inside `decorator`, which prints `"Function successfully decorated"`
5. We finally execute `f1` printing `"hello"`

When you call `f2()` again, you will go through the same code path, printing `"Decorator successfully decorated"`, then `"Function successfully decorated"` and lastly `"hello"`

Hopefully this step-by-step explanation helps you clarifying your doubts about decorators

Answer (score 2):

Your decorator got decorated just fine. Your "2nd-level" `decorator_for_decorator` decorates a "1st-level" decorator in such a way that when *the "1st-level" decorator* runs, it prints `Decorator successfully decorated`.

The message is printed when the "1st-level" decorator runs, not when the decorator is decorated, or when the bottom-level function `f1` runs.

Comment: But why is it when I decorate it the second way (the snippet that begins with `# this works`), when I *call* f2(), I get

1. `Decorator successfully decorated`
2. `Function successfully decorated`
3. `hello`

So, it *does* run when I call f2(), but only if I decorate via the second way.

Comment: @DLim: You did not decorate the decorator in that version. In that version, `decorator` generates a wrapper for `f2`, then applies `decorator_for_decorator` to that wrapper to generate another wrapper. You've effectively decorated `f2` twice in that version.